# Determine that a date is before or behind an age

Tags: java, date

Apparently in a simple problem but I am being complicated with the treatment of dates. I need a date comparator that receives as parameters a date in yyyy-MM-dd format and a number (age) and that determines if it is above that number or below.

For example for 18, 1999-01-01 is above and would return true, but for 2010-01-01 false. If it were the year 2001, it would compare with the current month and year, that is, 2001-06-18 that was greater or less

I have this code using the gregorian api for the current date but I am unable.

I have this done

```
    public static void main (String args[]) throws ParseException{

    //SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    //Date fechaInicial=(Date) dateFormat.parse("1999-01-01");
    java.sql.Datedate1 = new Date(1999-01-01);
    Calendar date2 = Calendar.getInstance();


    boolean res = date(date1, date2);
}

public static boolean date(java.sql.Datedate1, Calendar date2 ){
    //int year=18;
    int y= date2.get(Calendar.YEAR)-18;
    int m = date2.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
    int d = date2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    System.out.println(
    String fechacompleta= y+"-"+m+"-"+d;
    System.out.println(fechacompleta);

    return ;
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you are not using the `java.time` date APIs?

Comment: `new Date(1999-01-01);` is not a valid way to create a `Date` object that is set to 1 January 1999.

Comment: [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) is directly comparable...

Comment: Please clean up your code, it doesn't make sense. You have a method that takes two arguments but only one is used and your age variable is hard coded in the method. And it will not compile.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar` and `java.sql.Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Please search before posting a question. How to calculate an age has been covered many times on Stack Overflow (only avoid the answers advising the use of the outdated classes `Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`).

Answer (score 4):

You can write your `date` method using `java.time.LocalDate` like this:

```
public static boolean date(LocalDate ld, int age) {
    Period p = Period.between(ld, LocalDate.now());
    return p.getYears() >= age;
}
```

It computes the `Period` between a certain date and now, and returns whether that period is greater than or equal to 18 years.

You can create a `LocalDate` like this:

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse("2001-12-23", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

And pass it into `date`:

```
if (date(ld, 18)) {
    // 18 or above!
}
```

Comment: And since OP says the given date is java.sql.Date one can simply convert it to `LocalDate` with `toLocalDate()`

Comment: I agree with sweeper.I was about to write the same thing.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Actually the Question starts with a string input in standard OSO 8601 format, not a `java.sql.Date` object. I think this Answer is better as-is, ignoring the terrible legacy class `java.sql.Date`.